# AC for Geissler Tube?

Tags: electric-current

I could not find the answer anywhere so I am going to ask whether it is safe to operate a Geissler tube in AC instead of DC. I know that electrons get excited to a higher energy level by the high voltage, but does it matter if the current is alternating?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no problem with utilising AC or DC. What does your Geissler tube contains? An air or Ionizable metals?

Comment: hydrogen and noble gasses each with their own tube.

Comment: Then there is no problem with it. You can give the AC supply or DC supply but the difference is AC alternates its magnitude and DC goes directly. It will be advantageous if you could use the AC rather DC as you will be able to be delineated about the glow discharge better because constant alternation varies the magnitude(+ or -). I suppose this answer help you.